# IIS7 App pool crashing

Tags: iis-7

Any ideas?

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba2211c
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000057f91
Faulting process id: 0x1e40
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccbfff3d24cf1a
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll
Report Id: 8b4b0cd0-2bf2-11e1-9370-005056820010

Nothing has changed code wise. Tried diadebug 1.2 which we have gone through the exceptions.

Sorry not much to go on. If anyone knows best way to trap / capture IIS error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faulting module is C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll, part of VC++ runtime. As IIS itself is not dependent on VC++ runtime, it is obvious that your application leads to the crash. Dump analysis may help, but if you are not capable of reading the dumps, you may open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and consult Microsoft support guys.

DIY dump analysis is tough, but you can start if you insist,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lexli/archive/2009/06/29/diy-dump-analysis-possible.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not much information to work with there, but 0xc00000fd is a stack overflow exception. The most common cause is overly recursive function/method calls.